# Replace specific string with mixed characters in a column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like to remove a specific string and replace with 'None'
I would like to remove the Brazil (New) string.

Data

```
col1    col2
5   
5       Brazil (New)
none    2
na      none
```

Desired

```
col1    col2
5   
5       none
none    2
na      none
```

Doing

```
print(string.replace("Brazil (New)", "none"))
```

However, this does not maintain the rest of the dataset. I am still researching. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: `df['col2'] = df['col2'].str.replace("Brazil (New)", "none", regex=False)`?

Comment: Can be replaced from entire dataframe with [mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html#pandas-dataframe-mask) `df = df.mask(df.eq('Brazil (New)'), 'none')`

Comment: @It_is_Chris this didnt work for some reason

Comment: @Lynn what do you mean by "did not work?" Did you get an error?

Comment: @It_is_Chris no error, there was just no change

Comment: @It_is_Chris I think you updated , this may produce the desired outcome. I'd have to try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [`DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html#pandas-dataframe-mask) to replace the values based on where it is equal to the given string:

```
df = df.mask(df.eq('Brazil (New)'), 'none')
```

`df`:

```
   col1  col2
0     5   NaN
1     5  none
2  none     2
3    na  none
```

---

Specific columns can be specified and overwritten as well:

```
cols = ['col2']
df[cols] = df[cols].mask(df.eq('Brazil (New)'), 'none')
```

```
   col1  col2
0     5   NaN
1     5  none
2  none     2
3    na  none
```

---

Explanation:

```
df.eq('Brazil (New)')
```

```
    col1   col2
0  False  False
1  False   True
2  False  False
3  False  False
```

Then replace with specified value wherever it is `True`, in this case with `none`.

```
   col1  col2
0     5   NaN
1     5  none
2  none     2
3    na  none
```

---

DataFrame Used:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': {0: '5', 1: '5', 2: 'none', 3: 'na'},
                   'col2': {0: np.nan, 1: 'Brazil (New)', 2: '2', 3: 'none'}})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it this way:

```
to_replace = "Brazil (New)"

for column in range(df.shape[1]):
    col_name = df.columns[column]
    df.loc[df[col_name] == to_replace, col_name] = None
```

It should replace the value "to_replace" with none in any of the columns.